# can't send email from php-fpm

Tags: php, php-fpm, sendmail

I can send emails from the command line using sendmail,

I can call a php script ( php -f sendmail.php ) from the command line and the mail sends successfully,

but if I call the exact same script from the website ( https://www.bradfordjam.org.uk/sendmail.php ) I get a bool false and no email.

searching phpinfo() at https://www.bradfordjam.org.uk/test.php gives me:

```
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

which doesn't work. Calling

```
php -i | grep sendmail
```

from the command line php gives me

```
sendmail_path => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

which does.

Genuinely stumped. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like **selinux** issue. Try `setenforce 0` from cli, then send mail using web.

Answer (score 1):

drookie set me on the right path. All it took was

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail=on
```

so thank you drookie. have a much deserved upvote.